# Validation of read-only attributes

Tags: python, validation, properties

I would like to have some validation inside of a property setter in a class. This property has to be set during object creation and then it needs to be read-only from the outside.

I found the following solution and I wonder if there is a more straightforward or Pythonic way to do it.
(I am aware that by calling `user._username` from the outside it is still possible to set this property, but "we are all consenting adults" etc. - the important thing is that `user.username` should not have a setter).

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self._usernname = username

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.__username

    @property
    def _username(self):
        return self.__username

    @_username.setter
    def _username(self, value):
        if not value or len(value) < 3:
            raise ValueError('Invalid username')
        self.__username = value
```

**Edit:** In addition to the comments here, options for validation in the constructor can be found here: [numpy performance and random numbers](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-December/562185.html).

Comment: just check the value to store into `_username` with one underscore in the constructor, and remove the `_username` property altogether...

Comment: Do all the initialisation/validation in the `__init__` method. The additional `_username` property looks very artificial and serves no real purpose.

Comment: Thanks @AnttiHaapala, but then if there is no `_username` property, where can I validate this value?

Comment: Thanks, @ekhumoro! I might end up doing that, I just wanted to know if there is a way to do this with property setters.

Comment: @SamuBalogh. Just move the setter validation code into `__init__` and adjust accordingly. Get rid of the two `_username` property functions.

Comment: in `__init__`. As you said, we're all consenting adults...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala OK, thanks :) I might be too *protective*...

Comment: @SamuBalogh, The `_username` attribute is *internal* and should have no outward-facing api. It's only ever set *once* in `__init__`, so there's no point in creating a property for it.

Comment: See related [How to perform input validation for read-only instance attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367781/how-to-perform-input-validation-for-read-only-instance-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

Your example is interesting because you both have a need for **read-only** (that is why you create a read-only property facade `username`) and for **validation** (that is why you create a property also for the internal attribute `_username`, with a setter).

You can do the same efficiently with [`pyfields`](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/):

```
from pyfields import field

class User(object):
    username = field(read_only=True, 
                     validators={'should contain more than 2 characters': lambda s: len(s) > 2})

u = User()
u.username = "earthling"
print("Hello %s !\n" % u.username)
print(vars(u))
print()
u.username = "earthling2"  # <-- raises error
```

yields

```
Hello earthling !

{'_username': 'earthling'}

pyfields.core.ReadOnlyFieldError: 
   Read-only field '<...>.User.username' has already been initialized on 
   instance <<...>.User object at 0x0000022895908EF0> and cannot be modified anymore.
```

It is basically similar to what you were doing manually, except that it relies on descriptors rather than properties ([descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) is the lower-level protocol used by python behind the scenes in properties). Also, it only relies on a single "nesting" level: the internal attribute `_username` is a plain old attribute as `ekhumoro`'s comment above suggests.

See [`pyfields` documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-pyfields/) for details.